# How properly work with android internal and external storage?

Tags: android, storage, android-external-storage

i am creating Download Manager app  therefore my requirement is to store files on sdcard and phone internal storage if sdcard not available and access them later to open files from app.
i have read almost every post to store files but it confuses me to decide which method is best to use because there are lot of different ways to do.i want to create folder inside external(if available) or internal then store files inside this folder.
Now here can anyone tell me what is best way to access sdcard if available otherwise internal storage

Comment: You are only talking about internal storage and removable (SD card) storage. But the all important external storage you are not even mentioning. Please first learn which storage locations there are and how you determine them with code.

Answer (score 0):

[Storage options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.htm) in android is the place where you need to go.  You will know how to Checking media availability from there, more specifically [external storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

The sample code is

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */

```
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to access ExternalStorageDirectory

Comment: this will check sdcard state after that how can i get path to sdcard and create folder inside that path

Comment: Use Environment for that https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: `this will check sdcard state `. No. It will check the state of external storage. Look at the function name!

Comment: `how can i get path to sdcard`. There is no direct function for that. But this has been asked a thousand times on stackoverflow so a little googling will give you the method. Sometimes its indeterminable though.